# how should i loop for a top 3 ranking that should be in different places in design in a SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to show in the user interface of the future data in accordance with the design. But in the design, the 1st person should appear in the middle, and the 2nd place person should appear on the left. The third person should be on the far right. how can i show this in list loop. I am sharing my codes with you as an example. So in summary, the first 3 successful users will be forwarded to me in order of success. How can I get this display?

```
struct TopSortingUIView: View {
    var topSortingList : [TopSorting] = TopSortingList.three
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:24){
            VStack{
            Image("mangaa")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 77, height: 77)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 8)
                .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.973, green: 0.976, blue: 0.98), radius: 4.15)
                .padding(.top, 75)
            Text("User1")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            Text("2000 P")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
            VStack{
            Image("King")
            Image("mangaa")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 77, height: 77)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 8)
                .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.973, green: 0.976, blue: 0.98), radius: 4.15)
            Text("User2")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            Text("2824 P")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
    VStack{
            Image("mangaa")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 77, height: 77)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 8)
                .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.973, green: 0.976, blue: 0.98), radius: 4.15)
                .padding(.top, 75)
            Text("User3")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            Text("600P")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TopSorting {
    let rank : Int
    let photoUrl: String
    let userName: String
    let name: String
    let data : String
}

struct TopSortingList {
    static let three = [
        TopSorting(rank: 1, photoUrl: "mangaa", userName: "user1", name: "us1", data: "2824Ap"),
        TopSorting(rank: 2, photoUrl: "mangaa", userName: "user2", name: "us2", data: "2000Ap"),
        TopSorting(rank: 3, photoUrl: "mangaa", userName: "user3", name: "us3", data: "600Ap")
     ]
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the look you see in the photo. The data and image of the 1st user should be higher than the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to sort the items in the array with a custom function.

There are many ways of doing this. Here is something that can be reused.

```
//Protocol that requires that the Model has the rank variable (needed for array extension)
protocol RankingProtocol{
    var rank : Int {get}
}
//Declare conformance to the protocol
struct TopSorting: RankingProtocol {
    let rank : Int
    let photoUrl: String
    let userName: String
    let name: String
    let data : String
}
//Create an extension for any array that has objects that conform to the RankingProtocol
extension Array where Element : RankingProtocol{
    func zigZagRankSort() -> Self{
        var new: Self = []
        //Reposition the objects based on the original index (add to the front or back)
        for (idx, item) in self.sorted(by: { lhs, rhs in
            lhs.rank < rhs.rank
        }).enumerated(){
            if idx % 2 != 0{
                new.insert(item, at: 0)
            }else{
                new.append(item)
            }
        }
        return new
    }
}
```

Then with a `ForEach` and some minor adjustments you can display the objects.

```
struct TopSortingUIView: View {
    var topSortingList : [TopSorting] = TopSortingList.three
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:24){
            ForEach(topSortingList.zigZagRankSort(), id:\.rank) { list in
                VStack{
                    if list.rank == 1{
                        Image("King")
                    }
                    Image(list.photoUrl)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 77, height: 77)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .shadow(radius: 8)
                        .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.973, green: 0.976, blue: 0.98), radius: 4.15)
                        .padding(.top, 75)
                    Text(list.userName)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    Text(list.data)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }.padding(.bottom, list.rank == 1 ? 75 : nil)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Since I'm new to Swiftui, I can't solve problems right away. "for (idx, item) in self.sorted(by:\.rank).enumerated(){"- this code snippet gave an error. Error - Cannot convert key path into a multi-argument function type '(Element, Element) throws -> Bool'

Comment: @Aley I changed the sorting to the "older" version. You should consider updating your Xcode/Swift. There have been many changes in the last few years and some can't be overcome as easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like :

```
// Podium position view 
struct TopSortingPositionView: View {
    var topSorting: TopSorting
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            // only for first
            if topSorting.rank == 1 {
                Image("King")
            }
            Image(topSorting.photoUrl)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 77, height: 77)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 8)
                .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.973, green: 0.976, blue: 0.98), radius: 4.15)
                .modifier(ImageOffset(rank: topSorting.rank))
            Text(topSorting.userName)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            Text(topSorting.data)
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
    
    // the view modifier enable to apply the offset depending on the rank
    // you can put here other modifier for the image
    struct ImageOffset: ViewModifier {
        var rank: Int
        
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            if rank == 1 {
                content
            } else {
                // only for second and third
                content
                    .padding(.top, 75)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TopSortingUIView: View {
    var topSortingList : [TopSorting] = TopSortingList.three
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:24){
            // no need for a loop for 3 element
            TopSortingPositionView(topSorting: topSortingList[1])
            TopSortingPositionView(topSorting: topSortingList[0])
            TopSortingPositionView(topSorting: topSortingList[2])
            }
        }
    }
}
```