# In swift, Is there a way to differentiate Modifier or Function?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I read a swift code, I can see some code like .XXX().

For example `.padding()`, or `.shuffle()`

I knew `.padding` is kind of UI modifier, and `.shuffle` is a function of an Array.

Both of them syntax are ".XXX()", so is there difference between them?

I feel it is a bit confused to understand why Swift has both Modifier and Function, and Modifier looks like a kind of function.

Thanks

Comment: A `modifier` is a function that usually returns `some View` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier

Comment: Differentiate in what way? Modifiers _are_ just functions

Answer (score 3):

From a language perspective, there are no "modifiers" in this sense. [`padding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group/padding(_:)-8nx2) and [`shuffled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/defaultindices/shuffled()) are both declared as *methods*.

```
func padding(_ length: CGFloat) -> some View
func shuffled() -> [Self.Element]
```

It's just that in the [SwiftUI documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/configuring-views), they call a particular set of methods (mostly declared in the `View` protocol) "view modifiers", because they return a modified version of the view on which they are called on. For example, `someView.padding(7)` gives you a new view that looks very similar to `someView`, just that it has some padding.

> In SwiftUI, you assemble views into a hierarchy that describes your app’s user interface. To help you customize the appearance and behavior of your app’s views, you use *view modifiers*.
>
> Because **view modifiers are Swift methods** with behavior provided by the `View` protocol, you can apply them to any type that conforms to the View protocol. That includes built-in views like `Text`, `Image`, and `Button`, as well as views that you define.

You can find many lists of view modifiers [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view#configuring-view-elements), further categorised by what kind of thing they modify.

So no, there is no syntactic difference, just a semantic one. View modifiers *modifies views*. Other methods that are not view modifiers do not.

To complicate things further, there is a separate [`ViewModifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier) protocol, which is used in conjunction with the [`modifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/modifier(_:)) view modifier, but I don't think `ViewModifier` is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Both `padding()` and `shuffle()` are functions.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/shuffle()

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:_:)

The premise behind both is the same, to modify itself in a predefined manner and return the new version.

`.padding()`

> Adds an equal padding amount to specific edges of this view.

`.shuffle()`

> Shuffles the collection in place.

`.padding()` is for changing a `View` and `shuffle()` is for changing an `Array`/`Collection`.

`.padding()` is specific to the SwiftUI framework and `shuffle()` belongs to Swift.

Swift is SwiftUI's language.

The main difference is its parent object `View` and `Array`.

To create something like `padding` you would extend `View`

```
extension View {
    func borderedCaption() -> some View {
        modifier(BorderedCaption())
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier

And to create something like `shuffle` you would extend `Array`

```
extension Array where Element : RankingProtocol{
    func zigZagRankSort() -> Self{
        var new: Self = []
        //Reposition the objects based on the original index (add to the front or back)
        for (idx, item) in self.sorted(by: { lhs, rhs in
            lhs.rank < rhs.rank
        }).enumerated(){
            if idx % 2 != 0{
                new.insert(item, at: 0)
            }else{
                new.append(item)
            }
        }
        return new
    }
}
```

[how should i loop for a top 3 ranking that should be in different places in design in a SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74593121/how-should-i-loop-for-a-top-3-ranking-that-should-be-in-different-places-in-desi/74593350#74593350)